# Using Javascript to write html code and change file and description

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Hello I am trying to write coding for my website using Javascript and HTML. I have images on my website that I would like to have pop up or float on the side of the screen when you have your mouse over the link. I know I need to use onmouseover for this in the HTMl but I am having a lot of trouble understand Javascript and how to make this happen. The book I am using says to make add a statement to the function I made to set the value of the HTML code for the element with pix to the text 
are file and desc already in javascripts language? does it know what those mean or do I need to add cariables for them and if so how do I do that? 
I know it wants the file value to be the file name and the desc to be the text in the alt section of my HTML.

this is the coding that I made.

```
function switchPix(file, desc){
document.getElementById("pix").innerHTML=("<img src=\"images/file.jpg\" width\"480\" height=\"270\" alt=\"desc\" />");
```

### }

I noticed that a lot of the ways everyone was refering to the image was with http but the image i have is just an image file like museum.jpg that I am suppose to be taking from a folder and putting into the website. can I just reference it like normal? "

Answer (score 1):

If your images are part of your style and not part of critical content use them as background images and change them with css (img:hover for example). For effects use transitions and animations in css. It's 2016 and they are pretty good supported nowadays. This year I have moved as much as possible UI effects into CSS.

Solution for your question in pure js.

```
//First of all learn more about concatenation.
function switchPix(file, desc){
    document.getElementById("pix").innerHTML=('<img src="' + file + '" width="480" height="270" alt="' + desc + '" />');
}

//Place first pic you want people to see
switchPix("firstPicURL", "My alt");


var pix = document.getElementById("pix");
//Use second pic for mouseover
pix.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
switchPix("secondPicURL", "My alt");
}, false);

//Use firstPic for mouseout
pix.addEventListener('mouseout',function() {
switchPix("firstPicURL", "My alt");
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is the concat you're using

```
function switchPix(file, desc){
    document.getElementById("pix").innerHTML=('<img src="' + file + '" width="480" height="270" alt="' + desc + '" />');
}

switchPix("https://http.cat/100", "Continue");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/coins5/vu80586x/

Comment: please don't think and be sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you have tagged jquery, I've taken the liberty to use it.

Below is an example on how to do this using jquery, I've thrown in a couple comments along the way to help explain what's going on

Edit: Note that it does show the image in fullsize, but you will have to scroll down to see it, I've made a commented javascript where I hope you'll take your time to read the comments and try to understand what's going on, but you'll be the one to style it to your needs

```js
// The dollar sign is the object which contains everything related to jquery
// If you get an error about it not finding jquery, make sure you have the jquery script reference in the html.

// $("css selecter") - In this clase the class "picture"
// hover has 2 arguments, first is the function to call when your mouse moves in above an element
// 2nd is when your mouse leaves the lement
$(".picture").hover(function() {
// "this" is the element that is hovered above

// $(this).attr(propertyName) returns a property from "this"
// In the snippet you included, you added the the names of the variables as string literals
// That means if we do something like this

// var src = "image.jpg";
// var img1 = "<img src=\"src\" >";
// var img2 = "<img src=\"" + src  + "\" >";
// img1 is now => <img src="src" />
// img2 is now => <img src="image.jpg" />
// Be sure to understand what's going on in these 5 lines above, I do believe that's what went wrong in your own script.

 $("#pictureDisplayContainer").html("<img src=\"" + $(this).attr("data-displaySrc") + "\" />");
},
function() {
 $("#pictureDisplayContainer").html("");
});
```

```css
.picture {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#pictureDisplayContainer > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Out of pure laziness, I've used the same image for thumbnail and full-size, I recommend having 2 different pictures which are both scaled to match the purpose.</p>
<img class="picture" src="http://cdn.artobserved.com/2014/02/Andisheh-Avini-Marianne-Boesky-Gallery-8.jpg" data-displaySrc="http://cdn.artobserved.com/2014/02/Andisheh-Avini-Marianne-Boesky-Gallery-8.jpg" />
<img class="picture" src="http://www.wentrupgallery.com/media/gallery.jpg" data-displaySrc="http://www.wentrupgallery.com/media/gallery.jpg" />

<div id="pictureDisplayContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Including a sample snippet to play around with.

We have created a sample HTML page with few links and the idea is to show the relevant image based on the action (*here I am including `click` action / event; it can be changed to anything based on your requirement*) on those links.

To answer the questions:

> I am having a lot of trouble understand JavaScript and how to make
>   this happen

As stated, we have included an handler to the `click` event to the element `a`. Upon the action (which is click), the handler would be called with the parameters which we have passed. In this case - a *file* (an image) and *description* (description of the image).

```js
function switchPix(file, desc) {
  // construct the HTML
  var html = "<img src='" + file + "' width='480' height='270' alt='" + desc + "' />";

  // Find the element and set as it's inner HTML
  document.getElementById("pix").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
.navlist {
  list-style-type: none;
}
.navlist li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #F3F3F3;
}
.navlist li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #76432a;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>My Website</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="nav">
    <ul class="navlist">
      <li>
        <a href="#" onclick='switchPix("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/Bucephala-albeola-010.jpg", "Duck");'>Duck</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick='switchPix("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/08/South_Shetland-2016-Deception_Island%E2%80%93Chinstrap_penguin_%28Pygoscelis_antarctica%29_04.jpg", "Penguin");'>Penguin</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick='switchPix("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Kittyply_edit1.jpg", "Cat");'>Cat</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="pix">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> I know it wants the file value to be the file name and the desc to be
>   the text in the alt section of my HTML.

The JavaScript function can be constructed and invoked based on our choice. Coming to this case, we are giving an image element a source (file) and alt(description; when the image cannot be loaded, we have to at least show what we intended).